# Set local reference variable for dynamically created iframe in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

How to set local reference variable for dynamically created iframe in angular2?
I need to add **#dynIframe** variable to iframe. How to add?

Comment: you cannot add reference to dynamically created element

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to start with adding the iframe tag to the component's template. Then use binding to change the src property to point at the actual URL:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   ...
<iframe #dynIframe type="text/html" [src]="iframeUrl"></iframe>`
})
export class MyComponent{
   iFrameUrl: string = 'about:blank';

   assignIframeUrl() {
     ...
     this.iFrameUrl = // assign actual URL here

   }
}
```

Update: You could try something like this, but it would require compilation of the local template var. Without the local template var it should work though.

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit(){
    const component: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    let iFrame = document.createElement(' <iframe #dynIframe...> ');
    component.appendChild(iFrame);
}
```

Comment: adding dynamically is not possible?

Comment: It show some error:
**ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided (' <iframe #dynIframe...> ') is not a valid name.**

Comment: Use my original solution then.